# Can't push to GitLab repository from local server (hooks declined?)

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a local Git repository on the same server as a GitLab repository.  I could pull, but not push.  Since I am on the same server, I haven't bothered with SSH keys.  Looking at GitLab's hooks tab, nothing is shown (Note that I have never used hooks, and really don't yet know their purpose).  How is this resolved?  Thank you

```
[root@vps bidjunction]# git remote -v
origin  /home/git/repositories/root/bidjunction.git (fetch)
origin  /home/git/repositories/root/bidjunction.git (push)

[root@vps bidjunction]# git push origin master
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 2.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to access master!
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To /home/git/repositories/root/bidjunction.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/git/repositories/root/bidjunction.git'
[root@vps bidjunction]#
```

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on the version of GitLab used:

That hook seems to be active by error after GitLab 6.7.x: see [issue 6810](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6810).

> After the upgrade, pushes to all repos started getting rejected with the following error message:

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to access master!
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

> Downgrading back to 6.6.5 (and GitLab Shell 1.8.0) resolved the issue.

Note that it also mentions:

> The resolution is to update the ldap section of gitlab.yml, wrapping all values currently wrapped in single quotes in double quotes instead.
>
> Seems that only those using LDAP for auth are affected.

---

It could be also because the `master` branch is protected, as mentioned in [issue 6968](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6968):

> if I make `master` a protected branch, I can't push to it even though I am the owner of the project (see error below).
>   If I unprotect the `master`, then my push abilities are back.
>
> I am on GitLab 6.8.2.

Comment: Thanks VonC.  I am using GitLab 6.81 with shell 1.9.3, so that might be part of the problem.  I could, however, push to it from my Linux development server which is not located near the other server.  I expect it might have more to do with the master being protected, but then again, why could the other machine push to it?

Comment: @user1032531 is your push from the Linux dev server using a different user account? Or a different url (http/ssh/...)?

Comment: As seen by `git remote -v`, it is not using a url at all, but a direct path.  Also, the Linux dev server uses user "git", and again, the other server uses whatever username I am logged on at the time (which is never user "git" since I set up that user to prevent shell access).  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @user1032531 "Am I misunderstanding your question?": No, that explains the difference in behavior: the user `git` has access to the `master` branch, other accounts don't. Not sure why (it could be related to the issue 6968 I mention in my answer).

Comment: Think the best solution is just to allow shell access by user git, and just do my pushes that way?

Comment: @user1032531 that would defeat the purpose of authentication and authorization, so it isn't the best practice. It is best to use an authenticated account (and see if the issue persists from the Linux server)