# Cannot push to local gitlab server

Tags: python, ruby, git, ubuntu

I set up a gitlab server on my localhost. I have gitlab 6.8 version set up
I am not able to push. I am getting following error

```
fatal: 'myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I change my git remote add path to

```
git@gitserver:repositories/myrepo
```

Then i don't get above error.
I checked my gitlab.yml config file. I specified the repo path correctly. 
Why I am getting this error ?

After changing the path. If I try to push I am getting following error.

```
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 1.99 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to access master!
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To git@gitserver:repositories/maven-archetype/example.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitserver:repositories/maven-archetype/example.git'
```

I am facing this problem since last 7 days. I read every resource on this.
A SO question

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697580/cant-push-to-gitlab-repository-from-local-server-hooks-declined
```

It seemed to be a bug.
At the time of installation I compiled the ruby source so ruby and python lib is at `/usr/local/lib` path. I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH but the problem continues. 
I am not using ldap so no point to wrapping every string in ldap to double quotes.
How can I resolve this error ?

My gitlab.yml config file

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# GitLab application config file  #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#
# How to use:
# 1. copy file as gitlab.yml
# 2. Replace gitlab -> host with your domain
# 3. Replace gitlab -> email_from

production: &base
  #
  # 1. GitLab app settings
  # ==========================

  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: gitserver
    port: 80
    https: false

    # Uncomment and customize the last line to run in a non-root path
    # WARNING: We recommend creating a FQDN to host GitLab in a root path instead of this.
    # Note that four settings need to be changed for this to work.
    # 1) In your application.rb file: config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
    # 2) In your gitlab.yml file: relative_url_root: /gitlab
    # 3) In your unicorn.rb: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
    # 4) In ../gitlab-shell/config.yml: gitlab_url: "http://127.0.0.1/gitlab"
    # To update the path, run: sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
    #
    # relative_url_root: /gitlab

    # Uncomment and customize if you can't use the default user to run GitLab (default: 'git')
    # user: git

    ## Email settings
    # Email address used in the "From" field in mails sent by GitLab
    email_from: gitlab@localhost

    # Email address of your support contact (default: same as email_from)
    support_email: support@localhost

    ## User settings
    default_projects_limit: 10
    # default_can_create_group: false  # default: true
    # username_changing_enabled: false # default: true - User can change her username/namespace
    ## Default theme
    ##   BASIC  = 1
    ##   MARS   = 2
    ##   MODERN = 3
    ##   GRAY   = 4
    ##   COLOR  = 5
    # default_theme: 2 # default: 2


    ## Users management
    # default: false - Account passwords are not sent via the email if signup is enabled.
    # signup_enabled: true
    #
    # default: true - If set to false, standard login form won't be shown on the sign-in page
    # signin_enabled: false


    # Restrict setting visibility levels for non-admin users.
    # The default is to allow all levels.
    #restricted_visibility_levels: [ "public" ]

    ## Automatic issue closing
    # If a commit message matches this regular expression, all issues referenced from the matched text will be closed.
    # This happens when the commit is pushed or merged into the default branch of a project.
    # When not specified the default issue_closing_pattern as specified below will be used.
    # issue_closing_pattern: '([Cc]lose[sd]|[Ff]ixe[sd]) #(\d+)'

    ## Default project features settings
    default_projects_features:
      issues: true
      merge_requests: true
      wiki: true
      wall: false
      snippets: false
      visibility_level: "private"  # can be "private" | "internal" | "public"

    ## Repository downloads directory
    # When a user clicks e.g. 'Download zip' on a project, a temporary zip file is created in the following directory.
    # The default is 'tmp/repositories' relative to the root of the Rails app.
    # repository_downloads_path: tmp/repositories

  ## External issues trackers
  issues_tracker:
    # redmine:
    #   title: "Redmine"
    #   ## If not nil, link 'Issues' on project page will be replaced with this
    #   ## Use placeholders:
    #   ##  :project_id        - GitLab project identifier
    #   ##  :issues_tracker_id - Project Name or Id in external issue tracker
    #   project_url: "http://redmine.sample/projects/:issues_tracker_id"
    #
    #   ## If not nil, links from /#\d/ entities from commit messages will replaced with this
    #   ## Use placeholders:
    #   ##  :project_id        - GitLab project identifier
    #   ##  :issues_tracker_id - Project Name or Id in external issue tracker
    #   ##  :id                - Issue id (from commit messages)
    #   issues_url: "http://redmine.sample/issues/:id"
    #
    #   ## If not nil, linkis to creating new issues will be replaced with this
    #   ## Use placeholders:
    #   ##  :project_id        - GitLab project identifier
    #   ##  :issues_tracker_id - Project Name or Id in external issue tracker
    #   new_issue_url: "http://redmine.sample/projects/:issues_tracker_id/issues/new"
    #
    # jira:
    #   title: "Atlassian Jira"
    #   project_url: "http://jira.sample/issues/?jql=project=:issues_tracker_id"
    #   issues_url: "http://jira.sample/browse/:id"
    #   new_issue_url: "http://jira.sample/secure/CreateIssue.jspa"

  ## Gravatar
  gravatar:
    enabled: true                 # Use user avatar image from Gravatar.com (default: true)
    # plain_url: "http://..."     # default: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%{hash}?s=%{size}&d=mm
    # ssl_url:   "https://..."    # default: https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/%{hash}?s=%{size}&d=mm

  #
  # 2. Auth settings
  # ==========================

  ## LDAP settings
  # You can inspect a sample of the LDAP users with login access by running:
  #   bundle exec rake gitlab:ldap:check RAILS_ENV=production
  ldap:
    enabled: false
    host: '_your_ldap_server'
    port: 636
    uid: 'sAMAccountName'
    method: 'ssl' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
    bind_dn: '_the_full_dn_of_the_user_you_will_bind_with'
    password: '_the_password_of_the_bind_user'
    # If allow_username_or_email_login is enabled, GitLab will ignore everything
    # after the first '@' in the LDAP username submitted by the user on login.
    #
    # Example:
    # - the user enters 'jane.doe@example.com' and 'p@ssw0rd' as LDAP credentials;
    # - GitLab queries the LDAP server with 'jane.doe' and 'p@ssw0rd'.
    #
    # If you are using "uid: 'userPrincipalName'" on ActiveDirectory you need to
    # disable this setting, because the userPrincipalName contains an '@'.
    allow_username_or_email_login: true

    # Base where we can search for users
    #
    #   Ex. ou=People,dc=gitlab,dc=example
    #
    base: ''

    # Filter LDAP users
    #
    #   Format: RFC 4515
    #   Ex. (employeeType=developer)
    #
    user_filter: ''


  ## OmniAuth settings
  omniauth:
    # Allow login via Twitter, Google, etc. using OmniAuth providers
    enabled: false

    # CAUTION!
    # This allows users to login without having a user account first (default: false).
    # User accounts will be created automatically when authentication was successful.
    allow_single_sign_on: false
    # Locks down those users until they have been cleared by the admin (default: true).
    block_auto_created_users: true

    ## Auth providers
    # Uncomment the following lines and fill in the data of the auth provider you want to use
    # If your favorite auth provider is not listed you can use others:
    # see https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Custom-omniauth-provider-configurations
    # The 'app_id' and 'app_secret' parameters are always passed as the first two
    # arguments, followed by optional 'args' which can be either a hash or an array.
    # Documentation for this is available at http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/integration/omniauth.html
    providers:
      # - { name: 'google_oauth2', app_id: 'YOUR APP ID',
      #     app_secret: 'YOUR APP SECRET',
      #     args: { access_type: 'offline', approval_prompt: '' } }
      # - { name: 'twitter', app_id: 'YOUR APP ID',
      #     app_secret: 'YOUR APP SECRET'}
      # - { name: 'github', app_id: 'YOUR APP ID',
      #     app_secret: 'YOUR APP SECRET',
      #     args: { scope: 'user:email' } }



  #
  # 3. Advanced settings
  # ==========================

  # GitLab Satellites
  satellites:
    # Relative paths are relative to Rails.root (default: tmp/repo_satellites/)
    path: /home/git/gitlab-satellites/

  ## Backup settings
  backup:
    path: "tmp/backups"   # Relative paths are relative to Rails.root (default: tmp/backups/)
    # keep_time: 604800   # default: 0 (forever) (in seconds)

  ## GitLab Shell settings
  gitlab_shell:
    path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/

    # REPOS_PATH MUST NOT BE A SYMLINK!!!
    repos_path: /home/git/repositories/
    hooks_path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/

    # Git over HTTP
    upload_pack: true
    receive_pack: true

    # If you use non-standard ssh port you need to specify it
    # ssh_port: 22

  ## Git settings
  # CAUTION!
  # Use the default values unless you really know what you are doing
  git:
    bin_path: /usr/bin/git
    # The next value is the maximum memory size grit can use
    # Given in number of bytes per git object (e.g. a commit)
    # This value can be increased if you have very large commits
    max_size: 5242880 # 5.megabytes
    # Git timeout to read a commit, in seconds
    timeout: 10

  #
  # 4. Extra customization
  # ==========================

  extra:
    ## Google analytics. Uncomment if you want it
    # google_analytics_id: '_your_tracking_id'

    ## Piwik analytics.
    # piwik_url: '_your_piwik_url'
    # piwik_site_id: '_your_piwik_site_id'

    ## Text under sign-in page (Markdown enabled)
    # sign_in_text: |
    #   ![Company Logo](http://www.companydomain.com/logo.png)
    #   [Learn more about CompanyName](http://www.companydomain.com/)

development:
  <<: *base

test:
  <<: *base
  gravatar:
    enabled: true
  gitlab:
    host: gitserver
    port: 80
  issues_tracker:
    redmine:
      title: "Redmine"
      project_url: "http://redmine/projects/:issues_tracker_id"
      issues_url: "http://redmine/:project_id/:issues_tracker_id/:id"
      new_issue_url: "http://redmine/projects/:issues_tracker_id/issues/new"

staging:
  <<: *base
```

Gitlab shell config file

```
# GitLab user. git by default
user: git

# Url to gitlab instance. Used for api calls. Should end with a slash.
gitlab_url: "http://gitserver/"

http_settings:
#  user: someone
#  password: somepass
#  ca_file: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
#  ca_path: /etc/pki/tls/certs
  self_signed_cert: false

# Repositories path
# Give the canonicalized absolute pathname,
# REPOS_PATH MUST NOT CONTAIN ANY SYMLINK!!!
# Check twice that none of the components is a symlink, including "/home".
repos_path: "/home/git/repositories"

# File used as authorized_keys for gitlab user
auth_file: "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"

# Redis settings used for pushing commit notices to gitlab
redis:
  bin: /usr/bin/redis-cli
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 6379
  # socket: /tmp/redis.socket # Only define this if you want to use sockets
  namespace: resque:gitlab

# Log file.
# Default is gitlab-shell.log in the root directory.
# log_file: "/home/git/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log"

# Log level. INFO by default
log_level: INFO

# Audit usernames.
# Set to true to see real usernames in the logs instead of key ids, which is easier to follow, but
# incurs an extra API call on every gitlab-shell command.
audit_usernames: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to debug and resolve the error.

The error was due to ssh key wrongly set in `~/.ssh/authorized_key`

look into the production logs
The api request should be like this, Notice the key_id at the end.

```
Started GET "//api/v3/internal/allowed?action=git-receive-pack&ref=master&project=myrepo&forced_push=false&oldrev=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&newrev=34ddaaba32de91074e27a4cf3b9425a8dd92bbb2&key_id=4"
```

The key_id here should be the same as in authorized_keys file.

For more info [visit this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/7)

In my case I didn't ser LD_LIBRARY_PATH nor did I changed the quotes around strings in ldap configuration in gitlab.yml file. This error is because gitlab is not able to authenticate user. Gitlab authenticate based on ssh. This key_id will be used to authenticate the user.